# Runtime Error: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: types, integer, tuples

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Input, Conv2D, multiply, LocallyConnected2D, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
in_lay = Input(t_x.shape[1:])
base_pretrained_model = VGG16(input_shape =  t_x.shape[1:], include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
base_pretrained_model.trainable = False
pt_depth = base_pretrained_model.layers[-1].output_shape
pt_features = base_pretrained_model(in_lay)
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
bn_features = BatchNormalization()(pt_features)

# here we do an attention mechanism to turn pixels in the GAP on an off

attn_layer = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(bn_features)
attn_layer = Conv2D(16, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(attn_layer)
attn_layer = LocallyConnected2D(1, 
                                kernel_size = (1,1), 
                                padding = 'valid', 
                                activation = 'sigmoid')(attn_layer)
# fan it out to all of the channels
up_c2_w = np.ones((1, 1, 1, pt_depth))
up_c2 = Conv2D(pt_depth, kernel_size = (1,1), padding = 'same', 
               activation = 'linear', use_bias = False, weights = [up_c2_w])
up_c2.trainable = False
attn_layer = up_c2(attn_layer)

mask_features = multiply([attn_layer, bn_features])
gap_features = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(mask_features)
gap_mask = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(attn_layer)
# to account for missing values from the attention model
gap = Lambda(lambda x: x[0]/x[1], name = 'RescaleGAP')([gap_features, gap_mask])
gap_dr = Dropout(0.5)(gap)
dr_steps = Dropout(0.25)(Dense(1024, activation = 'elu')(gap_dr))
out_layer = Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(dr_steps) # linear is what 16bit did
bone_age_model = Model(inputs = [in_lay], outputs = [out_layer])
from keras.metrics import mean_absolute_error


bone_age_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse',
                           metrics = ['mae'])
```

I am getting error in # fan it out to all of the channels part at 'up_c2_w = np.ones((1, 1, 1, pt_depth))' saying 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs for the numpy.ones()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) function.

The function's first argument is the shape of the array (matrix). You can use either an int number or a sequence of int numbers. You are using a sequence (tuple) there containing int numbers and pt_depth variable.

**Check the type of pt_depth variable**. Presumably, it will be a tuple, though int is expected here.